# Obtener el valor de un Input

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola soy principiante en JS! Quiero utiliza el querySelector, o el GetElementById, y no me toma la propiedad .value. El editor me pone por defecto .nodeValue. Tengo q forzar y forrarle el node para q me lo tome el editor. A que se debe esto? les dejo el mini codigo:

```
<div>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" value=""> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

y el archivo JS:

```
'use strict'
var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').nodeValue;
console.log("hola" + nombre);
```

El editor no encuentra como suegrencia el .value
Mil gracias!

Comment: No veo como problema que el editor no sepa cual propiedad poner, digo lo puedes colocar tu así `algo.value`

Comment: Ha de ser problema de la inteligencia propia del lenguaje Javascript con el IDE pero lo correcto es 'value' y tu código deberia funcionar bien.

Comment: Claro, el IDE no me "lee" el .value. Lo tengo q forzar yo. No encuentro solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Como pricipiante es normal confunfir `nodeValue` con la propiedad de `value`..

Para obtener el valor del `input` hacemos algo igual a esto:

```
document.getElementById('input-text').value
```

Te presento un ejemplo que ocupamos normalmente siempre:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
const input = document.getElementById('input-text')
const result = document.getElementById('result')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    result.innerText = input.value
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-text" />

<button id="button">Imprimir</button>


<br />

<p id="result"></p>
```

> **En conclusion:** El editor Visual Code no sabe que propiedades mostrar porque estas trabajando vanillaJS y no es un lenguaje tipado..

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Se la diferencia con el nodeValue. El problema es que el Visual NO me lo toma como sugerencia el .value. No existe para el. Entonces lo tengo q FORZAR yo. No se como arreglarlo eso. Gracias por tu tiempo !

Comment: @Juan Si quieres autocompletado con Visual Code, te recomiendo ocupar TypeScript para este tipos de inconvenientes. Un Saludo.